# React Router + GTM, is there a way to prevent tags being injected twice when returning to previously viewed Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-tag-manager

I am trying to prevent the situation where code is injected multiple times when revisiting a previously viewed `Route`.

In a conventional site, the page is reloaded, and thus all the tags and their content need to be downloaded again, but in React, using `react-router-dom`, the history is changed without a page refresh. This leaves the previously injected code on the page.

I'm trying to gauge if the logic for restricting when a tags content should be injected into the React app belongs in:

1. GTM Trigger
2. GTM Tag

I cannot find any documentation for achieving this in triggers (as `tag firing options->once per page` doesn't work in this case), but achieving it in the tag code could be as simple as checking for the existence of an `id` wrapping the tag code, and preventing injection if it is already present.

Any suggestions?